# Removing the first element of a list within a list of a list

Tags: python, list

I want to remove the first index of each list within a list of a list. And create one list for each list within the list as shown below.
E.g my output is:

```
List = [[[0.75, 4], [0.43, 2], [0.29, 1], [0.03, 3]], [[0.77, 4], [0.77, 3], [0.55, 1], [0.45, 2]]]
```

And I want the output to be:

```
newList = [[4,2,1,3], [4,3,1,2]]
```

Im getting confused due to the list within a list of a list.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: I was trying to use List.pop(0)

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

Try nested list comprehension:

`newList = [[elements[1] for elements in nested] for nested in List]`

The inner list comprehension takes the second element of the list (elements), the outer does this for all the outer lists.

Answer (score 1):

One way to be more clear to you what is happening would be as follows:

```
new_list = []
for outer_item in List:
    inner_list = []
    for inner_item in outer_item:
        inner_list.append(inner_item[1])
    new_list.append(inner_list)
```

output of new_list = [[4, 2, 1, 3], [4, 3, 1, 2]]